# Regex to delete <a name=">...</a> and leave inside text?

Tags: html, regex

We have HTML code that looks like:

```
<h1><a name="_Toc22332223">Creating a record</a><h1>
<h1><a name="sectionB">Creating a record</a><h1>
```

Is there expression to use that we can find and delete the `<a name=>` and leave the text like this: `<h1>Creating a record<h1>`

We also do not way to remove other hyperlinks like `<a href>`

I tried `<a name="[0-9]*">.+</a>`  to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably save yourself a ton of headaches from fringe cases (something has 2 spaces, has both a href and name, no closing `</a>`...etc) by just learning to use a DOM parser.

Comment: Why not use [**DOMDocument**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: I laugh just by thinking of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1437016) whenever I see regex and html in the same sentence (no offense)

Comment: What result you are expecting? Does the original string get replaced? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others DOM parsing is the most reliable way.

But if it has to be very simple you can use the the following regex

```
<[aA]\s+name\s*=[^>]*>(.*)[^<]<\/a>
```

Example on http://rubular.com/r/cI2CTwUCy3